# Receiving the error TypeError: Parse buffer must be String or Buffer

Tags: node.js, parsing, web-scraping, xml-to-json

I've been getting the follow error in my nodejs api project. It does web scraping of a phone app web address.

C:\Program Files\GiustiziaCivileAPI-master\code\node_modules\node-expat\lib\node-expat.js:23
return this.parser.parse(buf, isFinal)
^

TypeError: Parse buffer must be String or Buffer
at Parser.parse (C:\Program Files\GiustiziaCivileAPI-master\code\node_modules\node-expat\lib\node-expat.js:23:22)
at Object.module.exports [as toJson] (C:\Program Files\GiustiziaCivileAPI-master\code\node_modules\xml2json\lib\xml2json.js:172:17)
at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\GiustiziaCivileAPI-master\code\setup_config\setup_config.js:33:41)
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)

this one file that seems to be causing that

```js
//setup_config.js
//This file is responsible for adding the user's token and UUID to the project via both method and API calling
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var xmlParser = require('xml2json');

var user_uuid = "";
var user_token = "";
var user_deviceName = "";
var user_deviceWidth = "";
var user_deviceHeight = "";

//sets the user info into local file vars
async function setUserInfo(uuid, token, deviceName, deviceWidth, deviceHeight){
    if(uuid && (typeof uuid == "string")) user_uuid = uuid;
    if(token && (typeof token == "string")) user_token = token;
    if(deviceName && (typeof token == "string")) user_deviceName = deviceName;
    if(deviceWidth && (typeof token == "string")) user_deviceWidth = deviceWidth;
    if(deviceHeight && (typeof token == "string")) user_deviceHeight = deviceHeight;

    if(user_uuid && user_token && user_deviceName && user_deviceWidth && user_deviceHeight){
        //add this user info to the XML file
        return await saveUserInfoToXML();
    }
}

//try to get the user info from the persisted config XML file and send populate global vars (user_uuid, user_token)
async function retrieveUserInfoFromXML(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.readFile('./config/config.xml', "utf8", function(err, data) {
            if(err) resolve(false);
         var jsonOfXML = JSON.parse(xmlParser.toJson(data));
         
                            
            //now populate user info into local var
            user_uuid = jsonOfXML.user_info.uuid;
            user_token = jsonOfXML.user_info.token;

            user_deviceName = jsonOfXML.user_info.deviceName;
            user_deviceWidth = jsonOfXML.user_info.deviceWidth;
            user_deviceHeight = jsonOfXML.user_info.deviceHeight;
            
            resolve(true);
         });
      });
}

//add user info on global vars to the config XML file
async function saveUserInfoToXML(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var xmlFromJSON = xmlParser.toXml("{ \"user_info\": { \"token\": \""+user_token +"\", \"uuid\": \""+user_uuid +"\",  \"deviceName\": \""+user_deviceName +"\",  \"deviceWidth\": \""+user_deviceWidth +"\",  \"deviceHeight\": \""+user_deviceHeight +"\" } }");
        fs.writeFile('./config/config.xml', xmlFromJSON, function(err, data){
            if (err) resolve(false);
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
}

//get the user info inserted by the user (returns a Array containing [User ID, User Token])
function getUserInfo(){
    var errorCode = 0;
    
    if(user_uuid && (typeof user_uuid == "string") == false) errorCode +=1;
    if(user_token && (typeof user_token == "string") == false) errorCode +=1;
    
    if(user_deviceName && (typeof user_deviceName == "string") == false) errorCode +=1;
    if(user_deviceWidth && (typeof user_deviceWidth == "string") == false) errorCode +=1;
    if(user_deviceHeight && (typeof user_deviceHeight == "string") == false) errorCode +=1;

    if(errorCode == 0){
        return [user_uuid, user_token, user_deviceName, user_deviceWidth, user_deviceHeight];
    }else{
        return errorCode;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    setUserInfo, getUserInfo, retrieveUserInfoFromXML
};
```

in particular these lines> How to solve this?

````js
if(err) resolve(false);
         var jsonOfXML = JSON.parse(xmlParser.toJson(data));
    ```
````

Comment: Please tell me the result of `console.log([xmlParser, data])`

Comment: it doesn't give any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's an error, you are resolving the promise but then continue to run the rest of the code, which you shouldn't do (there's nothing magic to `resolve` that will make the rest of the code get skipped somehow).

Instead, return after resolving the promise (also in `saveUserInfoToXML`):

```
if (err) return resolve(false);
var jsonOfXML = JSON.parse(xmlParser.toJson(data));
```

Comment: this change fix the "error" at the terminal and is possible to make a call to retrieve a court case information from localhost... but the result is empty and it shouldn't be, like in the image below... which I think what you meant is that it wont solve something wrong with the rest of the code?
https://imgur.com/uUkyP4L

Comment: @user18918352 that's a different issue altogether.